# Как настроить редирект с https://www.msk.site.ru на https://msk.site.ru

Tags: nginx, ssl, поддомены

Есть сайт доски объявлений. Он работает на поддоменах. Один город = 1 поддомен.
Например: msk.site.ru

Имеется ssl сертификат (https), который работает со всеми поддоменами. Все работает, все окей. 
Так-же есть редирект с www.*.site.ru на *.site.ru и соответственно с http на https.

Недавно выплыла проблема с адресами типа: https://www.msk.site.ru. Он показывает что-то вроде:

> Ваше соединение не защищено
>
> Владелец www.msk.site.ru неправильно настроил свой веб-сайт. Чтобы защитить вашу информацию от кражи, Firefox не соединился с этим веб-сайтом.

При этом такая проблема только с https. Тоесть  http://www.msk.site.ru будет редиректить на  https://msk.site.ru.

Настройки я попробовал вбить вот такие:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.msk.site.ru;
    return 301 https://msk.site.ru$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 443;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /home/site/www/prod/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/site/www/prod/site.key;

    #enables all versions of TLS, but not SSLv2 or 3 which are weak and now deprecated.
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    server_name *.msk.site.ru;
    return 301 $scheme://msk.site.ru$request_uri;
}
```

Вопрос следующий:
**Как сделать редирект с https://www.(...).site.ru на https://(...).site.ru** ?

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/10544

Answer (score 3):

Никак не сделать.

Ваш SSL сертификат является wildcard-сертификатом, поэтому подходит под произвольные хосты *.site.ru (третьего уровня) -- но wildcard-сертификат не может никак защищать поддомены четвёртого уровня.

За подробностями -- почитайте RFCI2818.

Вот ещё неплохие отправные ссылки на английском so:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115611/wildcard-ssl-on-sub-subdomain
- https://serverfault.com/questions/131431/double-wildcard-ssl-certificates

Цитата:

> A wildcard SSL certificate for *.example.net will match
>   sub.example.net but not sub.sub.example.net.

Comment: Расстроили меня чуть-чуть. Я брал сертификат вот тут https://www.majordomo.ru/ssl собственно вот "Comodo Positive Wildcard"

Comment: Тут есть еще Comodo UCC
Сертификат, разработанный для Microsoft Exchange и Office Communication Server.  НО он защищает всего 3 поддомена ?

Comment: Если вы хотите обойтись одним сертификатом, то это не-воз-мож-но. Не бывает таких типов сертификатов, вообще. И NAC, и UCC -- всё это не то и не для того.

Answer (score 0):

Вот часть конфига, которая проходит все(nginx1.11)
listen 443 ssl http2 reuseport;
        server_name test;

```
    #location = /update.php { return 301 https://test; }

    keepalive_timeout   70;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/test.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/test.key;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dh.pem;

    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!EXPORT:!LOW:!SEED:!CAMELLIA:!IDEA:!PSK:!SRP:!SSLv2;
    #add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
    #ssl_stapling on;
    #resolver localhost;
ssl_session_timeout 24h;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:12m;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload;";
    add_header Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only "default-src https:; script-src https: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src https: 'unsafe-inline'; img-src https: data:; font-src https: data:; report-uri /csp-report";
```

вытрете TLSv1

Comment: Собран с openssl 1.0.2h и даже хром кушает как родное)

Comment: Эта часть конфига не решает проблему топикстартера, это просто описание настроек ssl.